# Web-to-Case retURL

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, case, web2case

I have generated a Web-to-Case form and placed it in a Visualforce page the is on a Sites page. The retURL is directed towards another Visualforce page and I've set the object permissions and the public access settings. When the "Submit Button" is clicked, it just takes the user to a salesforce login screen and not the desired Visualforce page. I'm not quite sure what the issue is. Should a I be using a controller?

The return URL is of type

retURL ="https://c.na30.visual.force.com/apex/thanks"

Comment: Can you add more detail on how the URL format is .This needs more info

Comment: retURL ="https://c.na30.visual.force.com/apex/thanks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second page also needs to be exposed to the sites .

In your force.com sites configuration you can expose certain pages to the unauthenticated Users.

First step is to expose the thanks page to your guest user profile and add it under sites pages .

Your site will have a URL use that URL instead as redirect

so your returnURL = `site domain/path/thanks`